# Android application other than a gridview what can be used to create a menu page

Tags: android, gridview, menu

I have be looking for a quick way to create a menu page than can be used for different pages for navigation. Not including the use of gridviews. Using Gridviews I have found the following example on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hROz_XEQII8

However if anymore has other suggestions please comment below. Getting started with android dev

Comment: what do you mean by "can be used for different pages"?

Comment: By clicking on the icon it direct you to a page. e.g. contacts icon will take you to a contact page etc if that helps

Comment: have you tried the new android bottom tabview?

Comment: just asking if it requires you to use fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say intuitive approaches to navigation would be the [bottom navigation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) (as mentioned by @Mohammad Julfikar), regular [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), [View Pager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), or [Nav Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

If you want a view similar to GridView you could also use [Linear Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html) or [Staggered Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html). Although I think these are less optimal from a design standpoint.

Comment: I have already got some pages but to get the bottom navigation to work would I need to put fragments for it to work

Comment: Is your goal to avoid fragments? If so that kinda rules out the TabLayout, View Pager, and Nav Drawer as well. You could use activities but it would be sloppy.